# Document Viewer not using printer settings

Tags: evince, multiple-instances, laserjet

I have two HP laserjet P2035 printers on my system running Ubuntu 22.04. Each printer has two different kinds of paper loaded in different paper trays. Instead of manually selecting which printer and which paper settings to use each time I print, I tried to set up some printer instances for each type and have default settings for each one. This works fine except for document viewer. No matter which printer I select to print from, it always defaults to the standard letter, portrait, middle tray settings. Since 99% of the printing I do is from document viewer, this is a big pain. The settings are all correct in the system printer settings, and I can print from something like Firefox and it's fine. But when I try to print PDFs from document viewer it always stays on that default unless I manually change them. Is there any fix to this?